# Capture the click event of dynamic Buttons in Bootstrap Modal using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I hava Bootstrap model as below

```
<div class="modal fade" id="PQModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title " id="exampleModalLongTitle"><strong>Priority Queue Selection</strong></h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body justify-content-center">
          <div id="modal-text"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger cancel">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In this modal I am writing some dynamic buttons accoridng to the JSON response from server as below.

```
var scrn = '';
          $.each(pqueueList, function(index, val) 
          {

              scrn += ' <div class="row justify-content-center top-buffer">';
              scrn += '   <div class="col-6">';
              scrn += '   <div class="btn btn-block';
              if (val["fieldType"] == "EVEN"){
                scrn += ' btn-primary ';
              }
              else{
                scrn += ' btn-success ';
              }
              scrn += '" value="'+val["pqId"]+'"><h2>'+val["pqName"]+'</h2></div>'
              scrn += '   </div>';
              scrn += '</div>';

          });
          $('#modal-text').html(scrn);
          $("#PQModel").modal('show');
        }
```

I am driving to capture the click event on each of the button as below.

```
       $("#PQModel #modal-text div.btn").on('click',function(){
          var value = $(this).attr('value');
          alert("value "+ value);
        });
```

The modal is coming as expected and buttons are coming as expected. But the click I am not able to capture button click event.I am not sure, where am I going wrong. Please help me solve it out.

Comment: I should have asked before closing, are you executing your event binding before, or after the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attaching a `click` event before the DOM elements exist. This means the event listener is attaching to nothing.

You would want to use **event delegation** to properly handle this situation. This attaches an event listener to the **parent** container, and whenever there is a *click* inside of it, it determines if the element matches the secondary selector provided (*div.btn*)

```
 $("#PQModel #modal-text").on('click','div.btn', function(){
          var value = $(this).attr('value');
          alert("value "+ value);
 });
```

---

[Event Delegation JQuery Docs](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved me a big time...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that binding of the objects for the click function is happening before you complete the generation and display of the objects. To make sure, replace your third code block with something simple like

`console.log($("#PQModel #modal-text div.btn"))`,

and verify that at the time where this is called that objects are actually being selected